# snowflake sproc vs standalone sql

Tags: stored-procedures, query-performance, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, denormalization

I am thinking to create denormalized table for our BI purpose.

While creating business logic from several tables i noticed queries perform better when denormalized table is updated in batches(sproc with multiple business logic SQL's) with merge statement as below.

eg: sproc contains multiple SQL's like

1. merge denormalized_data (select businesslogic1)
2. merge denormalized_data (select businesslogic2)
   etc

Is it better to include business logic in huge SQL or divide it so that each query handles less number of rows?

Is there any overhead if I use sproc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking very generally. Snowflake is optimized to work in large batches. For example, I've had cases where it takes about as long to insert 1 record as 100,000 records. So inserting 1 record 100,000 times is a LOT slower.

There is certainly going to be some limit. A 1TB batch should be split up. And your mileage may vary depending on how/when/etc. you are updating the table. In general though, you'll find batches are more performant.

The only real overhead that I know of for procedures has to do with converting data types from SQL to Javascript and back again, and then how you have to manage the output. In most cases, this won't be significant.

Comment: Thanks David for reply.Our table has 400 columns .Actually i am loading 100 columns(50 M rows) with each merge statement to separate business function.

Comment: David is correct, though.  It is far better to add the business logic for all of your columns in one go.  Every time you run a MERGE statement, you are recreating micropartitions which contain full rows of data in them.  By breaking the MERGE statements into pieces, you are rebuilding the same micropartitions multiple times.  That said, you should also consider a larger warehouse to accomplish 400 columns at one go, since there will likely be a lot of memory/cpu needed.

Comment: Thanks Mike.Our business logic is complex and when everything is included in 1 big SQL,query is taking longer to run.Does merging data to temp table and inserting to main table at the end  avoid recreating micro partitions?

Comment: Whenver you create or mutate data in Snowflake you write new micro partitions.