# traditional star schema vs wide-table performance comparison in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When designing the data model for a snowflake data warehouse, is there a general rule as to what type of model will have the best performance? Specifically, compare a traditional star schema vs wide-table

A typical fact table has surrogate keys to the dimensions where fields such as descriptions are stored. What if the structure is further de-normalized and those descriptions are moved (or also on ) the fact tables? this is more in line with the "one-big-table" approach. Changes to the values on any dimension or a fact, would require a new record in the "fact" table which obviously will generate a lot more data"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on your specific situation to some degree.  When designing the schema, you typically have to balance the ease/speed/recoverability of ingesting data from many different sources/tables w/ a model that is easy for consumers to understand (e.g., write complex analytical queries) and performs well under load.

I've found that maintaining the core data model in star/snowflake format enables independent ingest/transformation/conforming of all the corresponding fact & dimension tables.

But then I have another transformation/denormalization layer that flattens that model into an analytics ready dataset.  Depending on the dataset size, and freshness requirements of the data, this can be accomplished w/ a simple CTAS statement off a view that pulls together the requisite data + swap (this solution can be run at any time w/ no disruption to analytics queries)

For performance reasons, flattened tables are essential for BI tools & analysts that connect live to Snowflake.  And for analysts who aren't masters of SQL, it abstracts out the complexity of all the underlying joins.

Comment: Getting away from JOINS is good because of the complexity for your users as well as the ease in which SQL can be created where the JOINS create huge volumes of data to churn through (many-to-many joins).  Storage is cheap, too, so I definitely prefer a flatter model when you can get away with it.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked in a lot of variants before, the latest being [snowflake sproc vs standalone sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59147564/snowflake-sproc-vs-standalone-sql).

Snowflake's hybrid column/micropartition table storage (and other databases with a pure column structure) means old truths are not valid anymore, or to a lesser degree.

If you have a star schema model it usually means you have a data warehouse that is updated by batch, and not by many small transactions.  This means that the cost of maintaining "one-big-table" may not be prohibitive and should be investigated.  One-big-table is surely the easiest for most data consumers.

Comment: I am a big fan of ingesting data and storing it as it comes to you, which is typically a more flattened table structure.  However, be careful with Snowflake if your table gets too wide.  Having too many micropartitions can create performance issues, as well.  Especially for the devils that use SELECT * against it.

Comment: Yes, widening a table decreases the positive effects of the column store in a micropartition accordingly, and there is a break even-point there somewhere (depending on the table content) where the column benefits are lost and the micropartition overhead still adds tax.  We don't want to be in that position...